# SQL Server 2012 - Find a steadily rising value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below:

```
ID  |   Name    |   Ratio   | Miles
____________________________________
1   |   ABC     |   45      |   21
1   |   ABC     |   46      |   24
1   |   ABC     |   46      |   25
2   |   PQR     |   41      |   19
2   |   PQR     |   39      |   17
3   |   XYZ     |   27      |   13
3   |   XYZ     |   26      |   11
4   |   DEF     |   40      |   18
4   |   DEF     |   40      |   18
4   |   DEF     |   42      |   20
```

I want to write a query that will find an `ID` whose `Miles` value has been steadily rising.

For instance,
`Miles` values of Name 'ABC' and 'DEF' are steadily rising.

It's fine if the `Miles` value drops by up to 5% and rises again.
It should also include this Name.

I tried self join on this table but it gives me Cartesian product.
Can anyone help me with this?
I am using SQL server 2012.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL tables are unordered.  What column specifies the ordering of the table?

Comment: Post your attempt at a self-join.   If you do it correctly it can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Let me assume that you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Then, you can use `lag()` and some logic:

```
select id, name
from (select t.*,
             lag(miles) over (partition by id order by orderingcol) as prev_miles
      from t
     ) t
group by id, name
having min(case when prev_miles is null or miles >= prev_miles * 0.95 then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```

The `having` clause is simply determining if all the rows meet your specific condition.

Comment: Shouldn't the having clasue be like min(...) = 1?
(instead of min(...) = 0)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Note: 5% case is not handled here

```
    create table #tmp(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(50),Ratio INT,Miles INT)

    INSERT INTO #tmp 
    SELECT 1,'ABC',45,21
    union all
    SELECT 1,'ABC',46,24
    union all
    SELECT 1,'ABC',46,25

    union all
    SELECT 2,'PQR',41,19
    union all
    SELECT 2,'PQR',39,17

    union all
    SELECT 3,'XYZ',27,13
    union all
    SELECT 3,'XYZ',26,11
    union all

    SELECT 4,'DEF',40,18
    union all
    SELECT 4,'DEF',40,18
    union all
    SELECT 4,'DEF',42,21



    Select *,CASE WHEN Miles<=LEAD(Miles,1,Miles) OVER(partition by ID Order by ID) THEN 1 
            --NEED ADD 5%condition Here
        ELSE 0 END AS nextMiles
    into #tmp2  
    from #tmp

    ;with cte
    AS(
        select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ID,nextMiles order by ID) rn from #tmp2
    )

    SELECT DISTINCT ID,Name FROM cte WHERE rn>1


    Drop table #tmp

    Drop table #tmp2
```